# confused about this demonstration of how mass is the integral of density

Tags: calculus

Below, I am confused about a few things the author makes reference to in order to show how mass is the integral of density. First, I do not see how the mass is K(d-c) as he says. I understand that d=m/v, and I do not see how d-c is the volume of the rod in that range. Second, I am confused about the dimensions of the rod; is the rod which is drawn two dimensional, and it is supposed to represent a three dimensional rod? I am unsure of the dimensions of the rod drawn and the rod which it is supposed to represent. Third, I am confused about how density can be represented at a single point; I am only familiar of an object possessing density, not a single point of the object possessing density. I would be highly appreciative of an explanation as to these matters.
thanks
[image]

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: @peterwhy yes, my mistake. Why is (d-c) the volume, however?

Comment: Does density here mean [linear density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_density)? For a section of this rod with uniform cross-section, the mass of the section per its length?

Comment: @peterwhy I am not sure; the description of density given in the image is the only one given. Is linear density what you suppose is being referred to here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rod here is a modelled as **1**-dimensional object, but you're thinking about a 3-dimensional notion of density.

For 1-dimensional objects, we can measure length and we can measure mass. The "density" of a uniform 1-dimensional object is then given by the ratio $\text{mass}/\text{length}$.

For 2-dimensional objects, we can measure area and we can measure mass. The "density" of a uniform 2-dimensional object is then given by the ratio $\text{mass}/\text{area}$.

For 3-dimensional objects, we can measure volume and we can measure mass. The "density" of a uniform 3-dimensional object is then given by the ratio $\text{mass}/\text{volume}$.

etc.

Does this help?